# "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event" with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I kept getting this error using Selenium Java w/ chromedriver on my mac OS (Catalina 10.15.7),

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
```

I googled and some people were sayin it happens when you have Chrome developer tools open on google chrome. I don't have any Windows with this open but it is still happening.

I am using **Google Chrome** version `91.0.4472.77` and **chromedriver** version `91.0.4472.19`. Any ideas of what's going on here? Sometimes I can get the application to run 1 tie successfully, but 90% of the time it throws this exception - what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `chromeOptions`, when you initialize chromedriver, add the following:

```
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Actually, it does seem like it's helping now I think.